# I am trying to pass data to my registration view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

it works well on my localhost but when i deploy to heroku it throws the undefined virable exception. My application can't seem to see the data passed to the view. 
This problem is peculiar to the registration blade.
This happens only when deployed to heroku.
This is peculiar to laravel's auto generated registeration blade and showRegistrationForm() function.

Here is my code.

This is the trait the renders the registration form. And it works well on my local host but not on heroku

```
trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, RegistrationData;

    private $extPath = 'ExtData/';
    private $currencyFile = 'currencies.json';
    private $countryFile = 'countries.json';

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {

        $currencies = $this->currencies();
        $countries = $this->countries();

        return view('auth.register', ['countries' => $countries, 'currencies' => $currencies]);
    }

 public function currencies(){
        $jsonData = file_get_contents(public_path($this->extPath.$this-`enter code here`>currencyFile));
        $data = json_decode($jsonData, 1);
        return $data;

    }

    public function countries(){
        $jsonData = file_get_contents(public_path($this->extPath.$this->countryFile));
        $data = json_decode($jsonData, 1);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

And my blade template:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('register') }}">
       @csrf
       <div class="input-group form-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
             <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
          @error('name')
          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
          </span>
          @enderror
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
             </div>
             <select id="country" type="text" class="form-control @error('country') is-invalid @enderror" name="country"  required>
                <option value=""> Select Country </option>
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country['name']}}">{{$country['name']}}</option>
                @endforeach
             </select>
             @error('country')
             <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
             @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
             </div>
             <select id="currency" type="text" class="form-control @error('currency') is-invalid @enderror" name="currency" required>
                <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                @foreach($currencies as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}} ({{$key}})</option>
                @endforeach
             </select>
             @error('currency')
             <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
             @enderror
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
             </div>
             <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="phone" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required >
             @error('phone')
             <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
             @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
             </div>
             <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email " class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
             @error('email')
             <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
             @enderror
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
             </div>
             <input id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required >
             @error('password')
             <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
             @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="input-group form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
             </div>
             <input id="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required >
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="register" class="btn float-right login_btn">
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Share some code...

Comment: Edit your question with the code

Comment: _"it throws the undefined virable exception"_ - Please show us the full error message and the code where it happens.

Comment: Maybe it's `$message` variable, can be others too just debug by commenting all  your variables and see what results you get from each one and u will eventually come to error of undefined variable

Comment: @xNaii. I have tried that. It doesn't see the data in the showRegistrationForm() function. It's like no data is passed to the view blade

Comment: @FranklinEkoh Then check file locations, check data in functions, etc.
Show your controller too, maybe there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
dd($countries,etc);
```

To see if the variables are set and what they contain.
IF you add all your variables, you might see where the problem lies.

Comment: I have already done that. I doesn't seem to pass the variable to the view. It doesn't seem to see the variables "countries" and "currencies" in the renderForm function

Comment: I might misunderstand but did you dd() the variables in the view or the controller or both? what do your functions return in the controller? An amtpy string, null, or somthing else?

Answer (score 0):

So, I made the mistake of writing the code inside the vendor folder, so when heroku downloads a new vendor folder and installs, it deletes my code. So, I have to override the function in my Auth/RegisterController@showRegistrationForm. Thank you guys